# colourful Noise in luminance filter opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, image-processing, filter

My final goal is to detect a laser line in my picture. To do so, first I convert my RGB colour space to HSV(in order to examine brightness). Then I will select only the pixels which have a certain value of H, S and V (the brightest pixels with a certain colour (red in my case)).

The pixels which satisfy these values I set their luminance for all 3 channels of RGB and if they don't satisfy I set them as black.

Here comes my problem and question:
[image]

[image]

[image]

As I mentioned, I would have either a black pixel or a grey (luminance) pixel. I don't understand how these purple or green pixels come into my picture. They are like noise and they are constantly changing!
At first, I thought I have these colour because of values bigger than 1. But I think OpenGL clamps the values to 0-1( I even tried it myself but no success).

Anyone know what causes this effect?
Any help or idea is appreciated.

Here is my fragment shader:

```
precision highp float;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;


const highp vec3 W = vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114);


void main()
{
 lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

 float luminance = dot(textureColor.rgb, W);

 float r = textureColor.r;
 float g = textureColor.g;
 float b = textureColor.b;
 float h;
 float s;
 float v;

 float min = 0.0;
 float max = 0.0;
 float delta = 0.0;

 if(r >= g) {
     if(r >= b) {
         max = r;
     }
     else {
         max = b;
     }
 }
 else {
     if(g >= b) {
         max = g;
     }
     else {
         max = b;
     }
 }

 // max = MAX( r, g, b );
 if(r < g) {
     if(r < b) {
         min = r;
     }
     else {
         min = b;
     }
 }
 else {
     if(g < b) {
         min = g;
     }
     else {
         min = b;
     }
 }


 v = max;                // v
 delta = max - min;

 if (delta == 0.0) {
     h = 0.0;
     s = 0.0;
     return;
 }
 else if( max != 0.0 )
     s = delta / max;        // s
 else {
     // r = g = b = 0        // s = 0, v is undefined
     s = 0.0;
     h = -1.0;
     return;
 }
 if( r == max ){
     h = ( g - b ) / delta;         // between yellow & magenta

     h = mod(h, 6.0);
 }
 else if( g == max )
     h = 2.0 + ( b - r ) / delta;    // between cyan & yellow
 else
     h = 4.0 + ( r - g ) / delta;    // between magenta & cyan


 h = h * 60.0;                // degrees

 if( h < 0.0 )
     h = h + 360.0;
 //HSV transformation ends here
 if(v >0.8){
     if(s > 0.7){
         if( h >320.0  && h < 360.0){

             if(luminance  > 1.0)
                 gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0), textureColor.a);
             else
                 gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(luminance ), textureColor.a);
         }

     }
 }else{
     gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 }
}
```

I have to mention that, the big white spot is sunlight and it's so bright that it passes my HSV conditions at the end. That's not my problem now, but these purple noise like pixels which are there or the green noises around the picture are my problem.

Comment: If you set R=G=B, they should be grey (or white or black). So I think there is a bug.  Do you mean you set "V" (of HSV) to R=G=B?

Comment: Please, post code so as to see the filter process.

Comment: No beside converting the color space to HSV I calculate the luminance value also:
Y=0.2126R+0.7152G+0.0722B
and then I set RGB to Y

Comment: How do you expect us to know what is going on if you don't show what you do?

Comment: I just added the fragment shader. It's just a simple HSV transformation and also luminance value calculated and at the end, I decide which pixels should be drawn which not.

Answer (score 0):

The purple and green pixels are probably uninitialized memory.

gl_FragColor is not guaranteed to be initialized at the start of a shader, so initializing it before the return statements on lines 70 and 78 should fix the issue.

If it does not and an uninitialized framebuffer is used, then it may be because of a different (and less likey) cause:

- It may be because of blending. Try disabling it or ensuring gl_FragColor.a is 1.
- It may be because the stencil buffer is exposing it. Try disabling stencil testing or ensuring that all pixels pass the stencil test.

Alternatively, if it is caused by blending of the stencil test, you could initialize the framebuffer with something like glClear().

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It should be exactly the uninitialized framebuffer.

Answer (score 0):

While your fragment "returns" without setting a fragment color, like here:

```
 else {
     // r = g = b = 0        // s = 0, v is undefined
     s = 0.0;
     h = -1.0;
     return; //<<<<==== NO gl_FragColor set
```

I think this code lacks a *else-path* for the cases `s <= 0.7` or `h <= 320.0`:

```
if(v >0.8){
     if(s > 0.7){
         if( h >320.0  && h < 360.0){

             if(luminance  > 1.0)
                 gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0), textureColor.a);
             else
                 gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(luminance ), textureColor.a);
         }
         //<<<<===== NO 'else' for h<320
     }
     ///<<<<====== NO 'else' for s<0.7
 }else{
     gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 }
```

Thus, there are many cases where the fragment (current pixel on image) remains untouched.

Comment: Ahh you are right. There are several places that I don't, do anything and simply return. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

So my mistake was some places which I have returned but didn't set the gl_FragColor. In my case, any where which the process failed or didn't meet the conditions I have to set:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

The corrected code should look like:

```
precision highp float;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

const highp vec3 W = vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114);

void main()
{
 lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
 float luminance = dot(textureColor.rgb, W);

 //RF: test
 float r = textureColor.r;
 float g = textureColor.g;
 float b = textureColor.b;
 float h;
 float s;
 float v;

 float min = 0.0;
 float max = 0.0;
 float delta = 0.0;

 // min = MIN( r, g, b );
 if(r >= g) {
     if(r >= b) {
         max = r;
     }
     else {
         max = b;
     }
 }
 else {
     if(g >= b) {
         max = g;
     }
     else {
         max = b;
     }
 }

 if(r < g) {
     if(r < b) {
         min = r;
     }
     else {
         min = b;
     }
 }
 else {
     if(g < b) {
         min = g;
     }
     else {
         min = b;
     }
 }


 v = max;                // v
 delta = max - min;

 if (delta == 0.0) {
     h = 0.0;
     s = 0.0;
     gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
     return;
 }
 else if( max != 0.0 )
     s = delta / max;        // s
 else {
     s = 0.0;
     h = -1.0;
     gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
     return;
 }
 if( r == max ){
     h = ( g - b ) / delta;         // between yellow & magenta

     h = mod(h, 6.0);
 }
 else if( g == max )
     h = 2.0 + ( b - r ) / delta;    // between cyan & yellow
 else
     h = 4.0 + ( r - g ) / delta;    // between magenta & cyan
 h = h * 60.0;                // degrees
 if( h < 0.0 )
     h = h + 360.0;
 //---------------------------------------------------

 if(v >0.8){
     if(s > 0.2){
         if( h >320.0  && h < 360.0){
             gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(luminance ), textureColor.a);
             return;
         }
     }
 }
 gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

and then it works great:
[Resulting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFzQU.jpg)